# Why is there a short between my VCC and GND in this circuit?

Tags: fpga, comparator, short-circuit, proximity-sensor

I am doing a project where I am using a FPGA board which connects to a circuit I designed. It has a quad Comparator ([LM339N](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm339-n.pdf)), a few resistors and an LDR; two distance sensors ([GP2Y0A51SK0F](http://www.sharp-world.com/products/device/lineup/data/pdf/datasheet/gp2y0a51sk_e.pdf)) are connected to it by wires, and the circuit gets it's voltage from the FPGA board (DE0-Nano, 4.80V). The comparators are also powered by the 4.80V from the board.

This is the schematic:
[image]

As you can see, the output of each distance sensor (this sensor only has 3 pins, I couldn't make the fourth hidden) goes to a comparator. The point was to turn the distance sensor into a proximity sensor and output '0' when it sees something at a certain distance. The FPGA then receives that '0' and acts. Somewhat the same with the LDR.

I can confirm everything worked when I used two different voltages supply when I tested this - one being 5V that goes into the distance sensor and one 3.3V that goes to the comparators. Both 3.3V and 5V came from a DC power supply.

Now, I'm using the DE0-Nano to supply power, the only source being one pin of 4.8V and one pin of GND. As you can see from the schematic, everything has one single power supply.

My problem - things are not working with the distance sensors; Trying to measure voltage at the output of each of the sensors I just get 0V, so obviously the comparators output nothing as well. I'm using a multimeter to try and check what the problem is, and when I tried to check for shorts (with a mode called continuity, I think), one of the following may happen (or together):

1. A short between VCC and GND - but there is no physical connection between them, I check that with resistance mode.
2. A short between the VCC and GND pins of the LM339N

1 and 2 will never happen at the same time.

3. A short between one of the outputs of the comparators (U1 or U2) and VCC. When this happens, The 3K pull-up resistors are also a short.

Like I said, there is no physical connection between VCC and GND so I assume that the short the multimeter is seeing is due to pins having the same potential?
Is it possible that the pull-up resistors are too small and that is why this problem happens?
Is it possible that I fried the distance sensors?

Thank you for your help, I have been testing this for days and trying to figure out what the problem is.

Edit - here are a few screen shots from scope:

1. This is the power pin:
   [image]
2. This  is the power pin, zoomed:
   [image]
3. This is the sensor's output:
   [image]

The output stays like this no matter what, so it doesn't really seem like it is working. maybe the amplitude is increasing but I don't think it matters (it could also be the other sensor and I don't remember).

Those screen shots are from one sensor only - the other shows different results, but when checking their output, none seems to actually respond.

Comment: Not sure what the overall plan here is, but you could likely swap out all the analog electronics with an embedded processor with multiplexed/multiple ADC inputs. Then simply program the processor for thresholds and possibly embellish the distance sensor with new features like hysteresis & noise reduction.  FWIW, the Sharp detectors are really not analog.  If you monitor the output closely you will notice a stair-step effect as the object moves closer-to / further-away-from the detector.

Comment: Have experienced high pulse current with some of these kind of sensors. A rather large supply bypass capacitor close to these sensors may help. *Some* Vcc-to-ground capacitance should be added in any case. (Spec sheet only give average current 15mA)

Comment: The continuity test function on multimeters does not indicate a short circuit (very near zero ohms) between its probes.  Instead it indicates a "lowish" resistance - perhaps up to 100 ohms - between the probes.  You should look at the actual resistance reading when doing this sort of test.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have fallen into a classic [*XY problem*](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=what+is+the+xy+problem)<sup>1</sup> trap. However, thanks for briefly mentioning the original issue, as that makes the overall situation easier to understand.

You have a genuine problem ("X"):

> things are not working with the distance sensors.

That is not enough detail to help you with the actual problem, but I'll come back to that. You are having problems interpreting the results from an (unfortunately inappropriate) multimeter test,  and *that* is what you were asking about ("Y").

However "Y" is the wrong issue on which to be spending your time, because getting an answer to that, won't help you with solving the original problem "X". As confirmation, below is the answer to your question "Y" (about the *apparent* shorts you measured) but it doesn't help resolve the real problem "X" (about the sensors, when powered by the DE0-Nano):

> I'm using a multimeter to try and check what the problem is, and when I tried to check for shorts (with a mode called continuity, I think), one of the following may happen [...]

Using a typical multimeter in that way on a board with ICs, will usually lead to lots of false positive *apparent* shorts displayed on the meter. This is due to the ESD protection diodes (and other ESD protection structures) inside most ICs, which can conduct during that "continuity" testing.

So stop doing down this rabbit hole and back-up a few steps :-) Here is what I suggest:

- Go back to your earlier configuration which you say worked i.e. external separate power supply for the 3.3V and 5V sections. I hope (and expect) this will work again. This would confirm your hardware has no "short circuits".

  I *suspect* that either additional output capacitance and/or a higher current capability of that separate DC power supply (compared to the DE0-Nano's power output), is why that configuration worked - see next point.
- Note that some Sharp distance sensors have unusual power requirements. Specifically they pulse their IR LEDs at relatively high currents, for brief periods. Due to those high currents, they are well-known for needing lots of decoupling capacitance *close to the sensors*, especially if the power supply is weak, or has lots of inductance (e.g. long / thin wires etc.). Your sensor's datasheet mentions *average* supply current (12mA to 22mA) but not a maximum current!

  Therefore use an oscilloscope at the sensor's power pin to view the waveform, and you may find it drops below the minimum acceptable power voltage for the sensor (e.g. in brief dips, when the internal IR LED is pulsed) due to the factors I mentioned above. I expect decoupling capacitors will be required as a minimum. That may be part or all of the reason why "things are not working with the distance sensors" when they are powered from the DE0-Nano.
- If you are still having problems with the sensors *only when they are powered from the DE0-Nano*, then focus on that and ask for more troubleshooting help. Show some photos of your setup, explain any constraints, use short power wires, expect to be asked to provide scope screen captures, and you will likely also need to provide info on the DE0-Nano and what power it can supply.
- See these pages for examples of info about those Sharp sensors and the need for additional power supply decoupling near the sensor; some suggest also adding a low-pass filter on the output signal itself, although I doubt that output signal ripple is your current problem:

  [How to improve Sharp GP2Dxxx sensors](http://letsmakerobots.com/node/22781)

  [Testing GP2D12 Sensor: Oscilloscope Traces, Capacitors, and Distance Sensor Results](http://www.robotroom.com/DistanceSensor3.html)

  [Sharp distance sensors](http://askrprojects.net/lego/sharp.html)

  and some other relevant Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange questions:

  [Can't get consistent readings from Sharp IR range detector](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8885/cant-get-consistent-readings-from-sharp-ir-range-detector)

  [Where to put stabilising capacitor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8915/where-to-put-stabilising-capacitor)

  [Daisy chain (parallel) of IR sensors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/103816/daisy-chain-parallel-of-ir-sensors)

  [Sharp Infrared sensor-Filtering supply ripple](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/217600/sharp-infrared-sensor-filtering-supply-ripple)

  [Where to place a capacitor to smoothen IR sensor reading?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17754/where-to-place-a-capacitor-to-smoothen-ir-sensor-reading)

  [How do I properly use Sharp GP2Y0A21YK0F sensor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/40216/how-do-i-properly-use-sharp-gp2y0a21yk0f-sensor)

  [Can't get consistent readings from Sharp IR range detector](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8885/cant-get-consistent-readings-from-sharp-ir-range-detector)

  [Sharp IR distance sensor outputting consistently high voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/59467/sharp-ir-distance-sensor-outputting-consistently-high-voltage)

---

<sup>1</sup> There are several *slightly different* definitions of the *XY problem* so I linked to a Google search above, for readers who want to learn more. The terminology I use is:

> "X [is] the underlying problem and Y the exposed question or request"

which is adapted from [here](https://daniel-lange.com/archives/69-The-XY-problem-in-IT-management.html).

Comment: You're right about not providing enough information - writing this question and drawing the schematic took a long time! :) I have edited the question, stating that the output of the sensor give me 0V, whether there is an object near them or not. Also, is there any other information I can provide?

Comment: About the capacitors - should they be between VCC and GND? Can they be soldered into the board I designed (about 15-16 cm from the sensors?)

Comment: @Eran - Understood & thanks for the schematic. It has confirmed there are no decoupling capacitors, so it has already been useful. While you updated the question, I was also updating my answer, and added an additional paragraph. IMHO you have several choices: (a) you could guess my hypothesis is correct, add (eg 47uF) cap *at each sensor* (not 15cm away) and retry; or (b) use an 'scope to view the waveform on the sensor power pins, in the "failing" configuration (powered by the DE0-Nano) and supply those 'scope screenshots; or (c) go back to the working config and retest, as in my answer.

Comment: Yes I saw your edit, thanks for the additional info. I am already planning to retest this tomorrow with the previous configuration. I'll also do what you suggested with the scope and provide screenshots, and if really needed, add the capacitors. I just really hope I didn't fry the sensors or the comparators.

Comment: @Eran - Great. As you said, I would also start with going back to the "working" config and retesting.  If that works, move forwards from there. Comparing the sensor power waveform on the 'scope, between the working (external power supply) and failing (DE0-Nano power supply), will help confirm or deny my hypothesis. However even if my (lack of sensor power decoupling) hypothesis is wrong, I wanted to help by stopping you wasting your time on those continuity testing results. Then you can move forwards with investigating whatever your problem *really* is :-) Also, see new links in my answer.

Comment: I added some screenshots from a scope. The comparator seems to be working but the sensors are not :( This is when testing with the DC power supply like I did once. Do you think capacitors will help here? Because if those sensors worked for me once I think it's possible that they are ruined and caps won't help in this case.

Comment: @Eran - Hi - Those bursts of spikes (notice the pattern in the spikes - 8 spikes then a similar length gap) looks like the sensor is *trying* to work. However I agree the output looks abnormal. I think this specific question is too "tainted" by the original multimeter testing question, to now be changed into what the question should be. I suggest to remove the scope photos from *this* question; start a new question (mention this one), give *brief* history, then add scope photos (power & output) from *both* sensors. Any difference in sensor behaviour may suggest (at least) one is now faulty.

Comment: [cont'd] Note that the recommendation for (at least) 10uF capacitor near to the sensor, is in its datasheet (I just found it near the bottom of page 6). Therefore you should expect to add that to each sensor, irrespective of any other results of your troubleshooting. I would start with comparing the outputs of your 2 existing sensors using just a scope (no attached comparators, in case any faults are dragging down the sensor output voltages), with power from the previous "good" 5V supply & short power cables. Any difference between the two sensor's outputs may suggest damage.

Comment: Agreed that the lack of decoupling is a problem, but even once you have solved that there is an unrelated issue, FPGAs of the reasonably recent sort will not appreciate having pins pulled up to 4.8V, R3,4,5 should be pulling up to whatever the IO bank voltage is (Likely 3.3v), no more. You may have damaged the FPGA at this point.