# MPU9250: VCC and GND Short but device working fine

Tags: arduino, short-circuit, esp32, imu

I'm facing a vague issue with MPU9250. When I tested with Multimeter, it shows that VCC and GND are short but the device is working fine, Output perfect accelerometer and gyroscope data.

My circuit is like the image below.

[image]

Comment: How did your multimeter show that Vcc and GND were shorted?  What mode was the meter in - resistance, continuity, or ??

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/276668/35022